# Substitute values in a vector (PyTorch)

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor of N unique target labels, randomly selected from [0,R], where N<R (i.e., my target vector can have any length, but only contains N unique labels.). I would like to transform the labels to [0,N]. Is there a function available for this target transform? e.g. input vector: [12, 6, 4, 5, 3, 12, 4] → transformed vector : [4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 1]

**My attempt:**

I have implemented the following snippet, which works as expected, but might not be the most glorious implementation:

```
import torch


def my_transform(vec):
    t_ = torch.unique(vec)
    return torch.cat(list(map(lambda x: (t_ == x).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0], vec)))


t = torch.Tensor([12, 6, 4, 5, 3, 12, 4])
print(my_transform(t))
```

Comment: just to clarify: what do you mean by unique ? your example input vector has 4 and 12 occurring twice and the indices in the transformed vector correspond to that; so I guess you don't mean unique in within the set of input values ?

Comment: Seems like `torch.gather` can help, but it's always a bit tricky to craft those.

Comment: @lwohlhart I have N=5 unique labels [3,4,5,6,12], randomly selected, with replacement from [0,R=12]. so I can repeat these 5 labels as much as I want, but can't have any other target labels from the interval. Does this help?

Comment: @lwohlhart In other words, my target vector can have any length, but only contains N unique labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [searchsorted](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.searchsorted.html#torch-searchsorted)

```
import torch

t = torch.Tensor([12, 6, 4, 5, 3, 12, 4])
transformed = torch.searchsorted(t.unique(),t)
# tensor([4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 1])
```

Comment: Wow, pretty incredible find!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @lwohlhart's answer, we can also use the `return_inverse` argument of `unique`:

```
import torch

x = torch.tensor([12, 6, 4, 5, 3, 12, 4])
x.unique(return_inverse=True)
# (tensor([ 3,  4,  5,  6, 12]), tensor([4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 1]))
```

Comment: ^^ this one is even more *wow* :-)